# Ajax url value to pass 'variable' to use in query

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I am in the midst of modifying a plugin in which I wish to get a value from a select list and auto-populate a textarea with values based on the selected value.

The php code come from a file named `wpf-addusers.php` but this file is not directly diplayed. The (absolute)url of the page that displays this information is `http://localhost:8888/dev_wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mfgroups&mingleforum_action=usergroups&do=add_user_togroup`.

My javascript (ajax) looks like this:

```
jQuery(function(jQuery){
```

jQuery('#usergroup').change(function() {

```
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "wpf-addusers.php",
      data: { usergroup: jQuery(this).find(':selected').val() }
      }).done(function( results ) {
      console.log( results );
      });

   });


 });
```

When I use "wpf-addusers.php" I get a 404 error like so:
`GET http://localhost:8888/dev_wordpress/wp-admin/wpf-addusers.php?usergroup=The+Freedom 404 (Not Found)`

`The+Freedom` is the value I want to use in my php code:

```
if(function_exists('home_url')){
$usergroups = $mingleforum->get_usergroups();
$team_title = $_GET[ 'usergroup'];
$team_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $team_title . "'" );
$players = get_users( array (
'meta_key' => 'team-meta',
'meta_value' => $team_id
));

echo "<div class='wrap'>
 <h2><img src='$image'> Add users</h2>";
echo "<form name='add_usertogroup_form' action='admin.php page=mfgroups&mingleforum_action=usergroups' method='post'>
<table class='widefat'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User group</th>
      <th>User names </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr class='alternate'>

    <td>"; echo "<select name='usergroup' id='usergroup'>
        <option selected='selected' value='add_user_null'>".__("Select User group", "mingleforum")."
        </option>"; 


        foreach($usergroups as $usergroup){
        echo "<option value='". $usergroup->id ."'>" . $usergroup->name . "</option>";

            }
            echo "</select></td>

     <td>"; echo "<textarea name='togroupusers' rows='10' columns='60'>";
            if ( isset($_GET[ 'usergroup'])){
                foreach($players as $player) {
                    echo $player->display_name . ", ";
                }
            }
            echo "</textarea>";

    echo "<br/>
    <i>The above players will be added to the group.</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='alternate'>
    <td colspan='2'><input class='button' name='add_user_togroup' type='submit' value='".__("Add users", "mingleforum")."' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>";
}
```

Does anyone know how I can pass 'usergroup' to my php code?

By the way, My javascript is enqueued properly on the admin side. So I presume I don't a specific handler function for ajax? (That isn't the question just a sidenote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the page URL is `http://localhost:8888/dev_wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mfgroups&mingleforum_action=usergroups&do=add_user_togroup` but you are trying to load `http://localhost:8888/tankards_wordpress/wp-admin/wpf-addusers.php?usergroup=The+Freedom`. Those don't match is a number of ways, but I am not 100% sure what the relationship between the two is. Your question is not clear in that respect.

However, even if you got that `.php` file to load via direct access like that-- `http://localhost:8888/tankards_wordpress/wp-admin/wpf-addusers.php?usergroup=The+Freedom`--, it wouldn't work. If you load the file directly like that WordPress *does not* load, meaning that WordPress functions will not be defined, and that file depends on WordPress functions.

You should be using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for this, as for nearly all AJAX used in a WordPress context-- cases needing extreme performance possibly excluded.

Write your PHP into a callback function like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    // your PHP
    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

And pass `my_action` as part of your AJAX `POST` data, like this:

```
var data = {
    action: 'my_action',
    whatever: 1234
};

// since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
```

([Both example code blocks more or less cribbed from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side))

Comment: The urls don't match because I edited the error from a different install. I tried to tidy it up to match but I see what you mean. I basically wanted to show that the value was being passed in the url but not onto the page where I wanted it to appear. My code works if I type `usergroup=The+Freedom`into the url bar but I can't get it from the select menu. The AJAX API is a bit beyond me and I think I'm going to have to pick apart the plugin and find another way to get the value. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The AJAX API is dead simple, seriously. Take few minutes to get that working. You will never look back. It solves a number of tedious problems with AJAX, and other "run code from an URL" problems too actually.

Comment: Alright, I'll knuckle down and have a look at it tonight. I'm sure I'll need it eventually and it would help me avoid hacking the plugin to bits. I'll let you know if I manage.